# creating auto increment id group by another column in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I would like to create an auto increment id for Project AR ID column - group by another column(Project associated ID).
Project associated ID is taken from projects list which is another list by vlookup column that the user choose from given options from project ID column in projects list.

I want it to look like that:

| Project associated ID | Project AR ID | AR title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | do this |
| 1 | 2 | do that |
| 1 | 3 | dont forget this |
| 2 | 1 | dont forget that |
| 2 | 2 | call this |
| 3 | 1 | call that |

Comment: This seems to be a Power Automate (MS Flow) task as, I think, it can't be accomplished using calculated column. Is PA solution acceptable to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can realize your design by **MS Flow**

**Please the following steps:**

`Note: When creating a new item, do not set value for the "Project AR ID" filed.`

1.Add a Trigger "**When an item is created**"

2.Add an Action "**Get item**"

[image]

3.Add an Action "**Get items**":

- Set Filter Query: **Project_x0020_associated_x0020_I/Id** eq **'Project associated ID Id'**

4.Add an Action "**Compose**":

- Type the Expression: **length(body('Get_items')?['value'])**

5.Add a **Condition**:

- **Project AR ID** is equal to **null**

[image]

6.**If yes**: add an Action "**Update item**", set "**Project AR ID**" is "**Outputs**"

[image]

7.**Save** and **Test** it.

[image]

-------------------------- **Updated Answer** ------------------------------

Go to the **List settings** to check the display name of the column.

[image]

Comment: Hello, First I deeply appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello, First I deeply appreciate your help. Thank you very much. Im getting this message trying to run the flow: "Column 'Project_x0020_associated_x0020_I' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user." while the collumn is totally exist and found. [img]https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/9278/aceopr.png[/img]

Comment: Hi, Osher Hen. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!